# Sum Running value with debit and credit based on cndition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query to running value credit with running value

```
USE tempdb
GO
DROP TABLE TestTable
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT, CREDIT INT,DEBIT INT, TXT NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO TestTable (ID, CREDIT,DEBIT,TXT)
SELECT 1, 10,-20,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20,-30,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30,0,'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 40,0,'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 50,-30,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 60,0,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 70,0,'A'
GO


  SELECT ID,txt, CREDIT,DEBIT
,SUM(CREDIT)  OVER(ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)   AS RunningTotal
FROM TestTable AS T
```

i need this query to sum based on conditions with debit or credit

```
if txt = 'A' then Running value + credit
if txt = 'B' then Running value + debit
```

thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample results to go with your sample data?

Answer (score 1):

This works on Oracle :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN txt = 'A' THEN CREDIT WHEN txt = 'B' THEN DEBIT END)
FROM TestTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just want a conditional in the `sum()`:

```
SELECT ID, txt, CREDIT, DEBIT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN txt = 'A' THEN CREDIT
                WHEN txt = 'B' THEN DEBIT
                ELSE 0
            END)  OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RunningTotal
FROM TestTable T;
```

The windows clause is (`unbounded preceding`) is unnecessary for the cumulative sum.  The `else 0` is to handle the initial case if `txt` is neither `A` nor `B`.  I assume you would want `0`.

Comment: Why you need to use `over (order by id)` ? A `SUM` doesnt care for order.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . This is a window function (aka analytic function) that calculates a cumulative sum.  You'll notice that there is no `group by`.

Comment: I see,  you are using `OVER` instead of `GROUP BY`? But in this case looking the sample data `ID` looks like a PK

Comment: With your approach on each line we'll have a different result for the sum. Replace `OVER (ORDER BY ID)` with `OVER (PARTITION BY 1)`  to have the overall sum on each line.